# Close access navigation pane even if there is no search result

Tags: vba, ms-access

When starting our vba-access-application (which is done by a VBE-add-in which starts a VBA-function) we used to close the navigation-pane with this code:

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acMacro, "Autoexec", True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

As I started to use the built-in search/filter bar inside the navigation-pane, this code did not work anymore when the macro "Autoexec" is not visible. So I changed it to:

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

This seems to work fine as long as there are any search results left. When I write "nothing with that name" inside the search bar(=the filter), the navigation pane will not close.

Does anyone know a way to close the navigation pane even if there is no search result visible?

Comment: From the context, I suppose you mean the "search/filter bar" in the Navigation Pane... as opposed to searching an Access Form.  So how is the code triggered?  You start out by saying "When staring out vba-access-applicatoin...", but why/how would you search for something when the app is starting?  (In other words, you have a lot of potentially useful information, but the overall context is not clear.  Please update the question and elaborate.)

Comment: @C Perkins: I updated the question.

Comment: FYI, if you want the Navigation Pane hidden at start up, there is an Access Option in the Current Database section which can be unchecked:  Display Navigation Pane.

Comment: Why not just disable the navigation in the start-up and be done with this issue? The instant you start building a application in Access is quite much the same instant you want to turn off the navigation pane. The nav pane is really for developers and not end users when you decide to build a custom application. So, just un-check the option to display the nav pane on startup and users will never see the nav pane. To flip back into development mode just hold down the shift key during startup, and the nav pane will thus display for your development mode and needs.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal: This if for me when working on the program. Not the end user

Comment: On application startup you have tons and tons of startup code that hides the ribbon (one line of code), the startup form, and of course the un-checked setting to show the nav pane. And of course a gazillion other settings you set that prevent end users from seeing and using the Access UI. You can't possible have all those settings run on startup if you going to develop or change code. So you will hold down the shift key on startup to by-pass all that code + settings (no setting or code will run). So you hold down shift key, develop . Exit and re-load without shift key to test in user mode

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal: You want me to exit and reload everytime I start debugging?

Comment: I am suggesting that for full testing as “user mode”, then yes a exit is required (or a quick tap of the compact+ repair button you placed on the QAT – that allows you to not have to exit). See my post here as to how this can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryModifiedDate"
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

In order for the command `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide` to successfully close the Navigation Pane, the Navigation Pane must have the focus.  But for an Access window to have the focus, a *control within the window* must have focus.  It turns out that the `NavigateTo` command will never place the focus in the Search textbox, so if the search results are blank and there is nothing to select, then *focus will not change to the Navigation Pane* (even though technically the Navigation Pane's selected group may have been updated.)

If you play with the Navigation Pane long enough, you'll find that the Navigation search results and textbox are reset when switching between the highest-level Navigation categories.  Hence my suggested code... it changes between two Navigation categories so that the search results are cleared during that action, so that the Navigation window will eventually gain focus when one of its listed objects finally gets focus.

(Really, using the `NavigateTo` command in this case is just a stupid trick to place focus on the Navigation Pane.  It's just another glaring deficiency of the Access interface that there is no direct commands/objects for controlling the Navigation Pane.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't write any code—but just use the built in Access settings to prevent (hide) the nav pane.

So work, then you hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key during startup.
(<kbd>shift</kbd> key by-pass).

## The shift key development dance:

You will find that you can launch + develop a lot of code and work on forms/reports without having to exit.
However, you STILL will have done a <kbd>shift</kbd> key start-up bypass. The reason of course is that on start up, you code may well hide the ribbon. (Or launch a custom one). Same goes for start-up form—it may run a bunch of code, ask for logon, check table links.

And then there is the start-up settings you have. You likely have a start-up form (you don’t want that running). You likely have un-checked the display nav pane, but you need this during development. And what about if you have a custom ribbon? (Again a setting in tools→options). And use special keys—again turned off for users, but REQUIRED for developers.

And then there is the auto keys macro. This is used to re-purpose the <kbd>F1</kbd> key (help—either disable or launch your own custom help—say a pdf or word file).

And any re-purpose such as say an <kbd>f12</kbd> to popup some custom search box etc.

So, all of these custom setup is going to be rather LARGE amount of settings. Many will be from tools→options (main form, ribbon, etc.). And some will be from your code.

You REALLY (but REALLY) can’t code out all of these settings, and some require a re-start anyway. In a typical application there really going to be a lot of settings that are changed for your users vs you as the developer.

On start-up you thus hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> key. This will not only prevent your start up code from running, but ALSO your start up settings – even things like nav pane, and especially the tools→settings area (<kbd>shift</kbd> key  ignores most of those settings).

So during a day of development, I will do this <kbd>shift</kbd> key dance all day long.
However, there are two tricks and shortcuts you can use here that will minimize this exit + re-enter down to a dull roar.
One great tick is to always place a custom compact repair button on the QAT. So QAT button is now ONE mouse click and always available to you. So if I am working on a form in design mode, flipping into view mode will often suffice, but in those cases where I need a full exit + re-start to test? I don’t even save the form, I just do a quick simple one click on that QAT compact + repair button.
One click! (Might have to answer yes to save). At this point, the application will re-start without you having to exit. And you don’t hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key—so all your start up settings run. You now flipped into user test mode, and it only took ONE mouse click.

This allows you to flip from developer mode and into “user test” mode with ease and only one mouse click.
So you can now run your application as it will appear to the end user.

To flip back into developer mode, just one simple click on your custom C+R button. (And you HOLD down <kbd>shift</kbd> key). This will flip you back into developer mode (you nav pane, your function keys, everything and all those start up settings are now ignored – you are free to develop without all those hassles and issues in your way). Full wide open use of Access as if no settings at all occurred.

And as noted, you get a c+r to boot, and you need + want to do that multiple times during the day anyway.
And as noted, for a good many changes, you not have to do this flip and can stay in developer mode.
Of course in some cases your “user mode” will REALLY lock down the Access and thus you have to exit (you lose the QAT trick). So you often be able to jump from developer to user, but not back the other way. Again, you not have to run + test everything in user mode all the time, but often some global variables, start up, password stuff will force this issue on you.

So, in this case?

I use a quick hit of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> to exit the application. AT this point, the accDB file should STILL be highlighted in the windows explorer. So, now it just a quick tap of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to re-launch the accDB. And if wanting “user mode”, then simply don’t hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. Do some testing, now <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, and then a simple quick tap of the <kbd>enter</kbd> key (we back to the windows file explore and that accDB file is highlight). However, this time you WILL hold down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, and thus you now back into developer mode.
And often, I will call my start up code before testing.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (jumps to debug window), type in MyStartup

(MyStartup is assumed to be your first start up routine that does all that setup and THEN launches the main form – so in some applications I don’t use the built in start-up form setting, but use the autoexec macro to call my main start up routine (MyStartup)

So in a good many cases, I don’t have to exit Access to flip into test mode.

And of course some reports and forms can be used, viewed, developed on without having to full run the application with all that “user” start-up code stuff.

So some report might work, but then again it may well require some form to be open for it to work. (Or a system wide function and company name setting may be required + set in your start up code). So how badly you need to exit vs that of being able to do “some” development will often vary here.

So I will say that often I am forced to exit + re-load the application (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, tap <kbd>enter</kbd> key). So it only really 2 key combo to exit out and re-load/re-enter Access.

At the end of the day, if you can’t use that QAT shortcut suggestion, then you will exit + re-enter MANY MANY times during the day.
As noted, for a good number of forms etc., then you can flip between view and design mode. (But you of course be running access without all that start up crap stuff that prevents you the developer from working).

The simple matter is at the end of the day, there is going to be FAR MORE settings then just the nav pane (or lack of) that going to mess up your development process. So, the above <kbd>shift</kbd> key dance and QAT suggestion ALSO solves all of the OTHER many settings, and does so without you having to write one line of code to deal with this issue.

Of course, once all is working, then you will compile the application down to an accDE. And then apply the <kbd>shift</kbd> key by-pass code to that to lock the application further down.